# Bach French Suite BWV 816: Allemande - what is the ornament with the swoosh at the end?

Tags: notation, ornaments, performance-practice

I am using this [reference for ornamentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20211021113229/https://www.henle.de/media/foreword/1816.pdf) from the Foreword of [J.S. Bach 16 well-known original pieces](https://www.henle.de/At-the-Piano-16-well-known-original-pieces/HN-1816) (Henle). The ornament in bar 9 looks like "idem" but the swoosh comes at the end (instead of at the beginning).

I would appreciate advice on how to realise this.

Wikipedia calls this a slide: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_(musical_ornament) — but again the swoosh is at the beginning...

[image: Allemande m. 9]

Schiff doesn't ornament the G5 at first; during the repeat it sounds like a short upward scale:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, *idem* is not the name of an ornament but a Latin word meaning "the same."  The ornament you're referring to, therefore, is called *Doppelt-Cadence,* but is the second example of that ornament.

But the ornament you're asking about is called *Schleifer.*  While the forms given in the Wikipedia article you link to show the swoosh at the beginning, this is the form preferred by Bach (and, I suppose, by everyone else in 18th-century Germany).

The ornament is explained in C. P. E. Bach's *[Versuch über die wahre Art das Clavier zu spielen](https://imslp.org/wiki/Versuch_%C3%BCber_die_wahre_Art_das_Clavier_zu_spielen,_H.868,_870_(Bach,_Carl_Philipp_Emanuel))* as two quick notes ascending to the main note.  (The *Schleifer von dreyen Nötgen* has a different symbol and is performed somewhat differently.)

The German text is available [on Wikisource](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Versuch_%C3%BCber_die_wahre_Art_das_Clavier_zu_spielen/T1H2A7_Schleifer), as are the [tables of figures](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Versuch_%C3%BCber_die_wahre_Art_das_Clavier_zu_spielen/T1V1_Exempel).  The sign used in the Allemande is seen at figure 88(a) in table 6.